# How to resolve issue where table column is too narrow?

Tags: html, css

I'm new on this particular project, and I've been tasked with resolving an issue that's appearing in IE8.

If you check http://funds.ft.com/ETFHomepage.aspx, There's a section called "News". In that section, there's a column called "Most Popular ETFs". This should be the same width as the "Recently Viewed ETFs" column.

For reference, this page is appearing correctly in Firefox. Can somebody please point out what I can do with CSS or (some other means)* to resolve this?

*I know the best way to resolve this issue is to scrap the terrible design and implement it correctly!! :-) -- we're actually doing that right now. It's a big job, so it's taking a long time. In the mean time however, we have to fix the bugs as they appear. Thanks

**Update:** just to note what I've said to Hristo, "I think the problem is with the table (rather, nested tables) on the left. The table in the center has its width defined by the image, and the table on the right doesn't have an image so it gets crushed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason this is happening is because of the url you have under the "Alphaville: Overcoming the Volcker rule, with ETFs" header. Since the url has no whitespace in it, the table tries to give it space. So there are a couple of ways to fix this problem:

1. Plain text urls aren't very becoming on a webpage (especially when they're not in anchor tags so you can click on them.) Could you update the content so that you don't have a raw url in your content?
2. If you must be able to handle long lines of text with no whitespace then you need to figure out how to change the layout of the page so it forces the text to either wrap or clip to fit the container. Try playing around with putting "table-layout: fixed" on your tables to force the column widths to be sized based on the table's specifications only (instead of content). Firefox seems to be wrapping on dashes and slashes in the url whereas IE only wants to wrap on the dashes in the url.

I would say your layout is fine, and you just need to fix the content generation so it doesn't include any long plain text urls (option 1 above)

EDIT: If you do decide to go with option 2 above, then look into the css rule "word-break: break-all". It is IE only and it forces the text to break as soon as it reaches the end of the container. Not good for words, but it works for url's. So you couldn't apply this to the whole news table, but you could to just the cell that contains the url.